# How to select all data from Data Frame?

Tags: python, select, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, series

I want to select all data inside a Data Frame (except index, column indices and right-most column - see the image below) and store it into a Series. This might be obvious, but I cannot get anything working. I have tried for example `a = nai_data.ix[0:19]`but it returns a new Data Frame again with all indices and I need just a Series of data. So I tried `a = pd.Series(nai_data.ix[0:19])` but didnt help either. I am sure there must be a simple way to do this but cant find out. Any help appreciated[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [`stack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), which can be thought of as moving the column index into the row index:

```
In [12]: np.random.seed(2015)

In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,4)))

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  2  2  9  6
1  8  5  7  8
2  0  6  7  8

In [15]: df.stack()
Out[15]: 
0  0    2
   1    2
   2    9
   3    6
1  0    8
   1    5
   2    7
   3    8
2  0    0
   1    6
   2    7
   3    8
dtype: int64
```

If you don't want the MultiIndex, call `reset_index()`:

```
In [16]: df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[16]: 
0     2
1     2
2     9
3     6
4     8
5     5
6     7
7     8
8     0
9     6
10    7
11    8
dtype: int64
```

---

To select all but the last column, you could use [`df.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data):

```
In [17]: df.iloc[:, :-1]
Out[17]: 
   0  1  2
0  2  2  9
1  8  5  7
2  0  6  7

In [18]: df.iloc[:, :-1].stack()
Out[18]: 
0  0    2
   1    2
   2    9
1  0    8
   1    5
   2    7
2  0    0
   1    6
   2    7
dtype: int64
```

---

Another way would be to slice and flatten the underlying NumPy array:

```
In [21]: df.values
Out[21]: 
array([[2, 2, 9, 6],
       [8, 5, 7, 8],
       [0, 6, 7, 8]])

In [22]: df.values[:, :-1]
Out[22]: 
array([[2, 2, 9],
       [8, 5, 7],
       [0, 6, 7]])

In [23]: df.values[:, :-1].ravel()
Out[23]: array([2, 2, 9, 8, 5, 7, 0, 6, 7])
```

and then just build the Series using this data:

```
In [24]: pd.Series(df.values[:, :-1].ravel())
Out[24]: 
0    2
1    2
2    9
3    8
4    5
5    7
6    0
7    6
8    7
dtype: int64
```

Comment: yes this works fine but it retrieves all columns and i cant retrieve the right-most column. is there any way to specifiy the range of columns or any other way to do this?